# Power of positive operator

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $B(H)$ be the space of all bounded linear operator on $H$. Let $T\in B(H)$ be a positive operator ($\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in H$) and $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. I want to show $T^{\alpha}$ is positive.

I used continuous functional calculus $\left(\sigma (f(T))=f(\sigma (T)\right)$ to show. I took $f(z)=z^{\alpha}$ which is continuous for $z\geq0$.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Yes, but I assume this is not really the question you want to ask.  If you are not sure of the correctness of your proof, there must be some point that you do not understand, or are unsure of.  You may want to emphasize the part that is unclear and make it the focus of your question.

Comment: @guest I told my question "I want to show $T^{\alpha}$ is positive."

Comment: your problem statement is not correct. Take e.g. $\alpha=-1$.

Comment: @YuriiSavchuk If $T$ is positive and invertible, then $T^{-1}$ is positive as well. Namely, every $x\in H$ is of the form $Ty$ for some $y\in H$ and therefore $\langle T^{-1}x,x\rangle=\langle y,Ty\rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: @Janko Bracic Yes, if $T^{-1}$ is well-defined.